# Cargar archivos de una extensión concreta en un jComboBox Java

Tags: java, archivo

Quiero insertar en **items** cada uno de los ficheros con una extensión concreta de un directorio determinado.

En mi caso, controlar los ficheros **.txt** de mi Escritorio y colocarlos en el `Combobox`.

**Código:**

```
package leertxts;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

public class MostrarTXTs extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    String ubicacion = "C:\\Users\\Nombre\\Desktop";
    File contenedor = new File(ubicacion);
    File[] registros = contenedor.listFiles();

    private void MostrarCombo() {
        for (int i = 0; i < registros.length; i++) {
            combobox.addItem(registros[i].getName().endsWith("txt"));
        }
    }

    public MostrarTXTs() {
        initComponents();
        MostrarCombo();
    }
}
```

¿Por qué no me aparecen los nombres en el combobox y sí me aparece true o false?

Comment: Creo que te has equivocado con el literal en *System.getProperty()*

Comment: Cierto, eso está resuelto pero ahora en el combobox me aparecen: false, false, false, true, false, false... y no en cambio los nombres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema radica en la forma como funciona el método [endsWith](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith(java.lang.String)). Este método retorna `true` si el sufijo `txt` se encuentra en la cadena, de lo contrario, devuelve `false`. Esa es la razón del porque en el combobox muestra valores booleanos.

Una posible solución es usar el método [replaceFirst](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). Este método eliminará una parte especifica de la cadena, en la cual, retornará un nuevo objeto de tipo `String` con los cambios hecho.

Por ejemplo:

```java
public class Program 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String nameFile = "myFile.txt";
        String result = nameFile.replaceFirst(".txt", "");
        System.out.println("String: "+result + " , Length: "+ result.length());

    } 
}
```

Salida por pantalla:

```java
String: myFile, Length: 6
```

Entonces, el código del combobox quedaría así:

```java
combobox.addItem(registros[i].getName().replaceFirst(".txt", ""));
```

De este modo, podrás obtener los nombres de cada archivo sin la extensión.